# Jekyll liquid split by '---'

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm looking for code to split content of md file when generating jekyll site by string `'---'`.

When I do `{% assign blocks = content | split:'<!--break-->' %}` all is ok.

But `{% assign blocks = content | split:'---' %}` not working, how to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three dashes are needed to split your frontmatter from the content. You'll need to use another string as a separator.